# Finding block of text with different formatting in Word document using Macros

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on creating a macro in Microsoft Word (2007) for a document that contains text such as this:

> **(1) Bold heading.** Normal text.

With this text I'd like to perform a number of transformations upon the first part - **(1) Bold heading.** - of that text.

While "(1)" and "Bold heading." have a consistent style (bold and Arial), the space *between* the two does not (it's Times New Roman, non-bold).

I thought a search for the below would work, without any format restrictions.

```
"^13(\([0-9]@\)) (?@)."
```

Unfortunately, there's also cases where text is as follows:

> **(1)** Normal text.

For blocks like this, I want to completely *skip* the text.

Unfortunately, my wildcard search is going to find these instances too, unless I can restrict it by font styles.

If I could normalize the space in the first case, then I could add the Font restrictions on my wildcard search to grab the correct content.

```
.Text = "^13(\([0-9]@\)) (?@)."
.Font.Name = "Arial"
.Font.Size = 9
.Font.Bold = True
```

But, I'd need to be able to grab two differently formatted items in a search to normalize that space, which, from my limited knowledge of VBA, doesn't appear to be possible.

Is there a way to find text with different formatting, in a Word macro?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not quite sure where the difficulty is, you can examine the document sentence by sentence or character by character. Perhaps you could add a line or two to your post?

Comment: Thanks Remou. I've updated the question to clarify that I want to transform that block of text, and stressed that my search would find too many instances. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if something like this would suit:

```
Dim s As Range
Dim wd As Range
Dim BoldHead As Boolean
Dim doc As Document

Set doc = Word.Documents("Doc2.doc")

For Each s In doc.Sentences
    If s.Words(1).Bold = True Then
        BoldHead = True
        For Each wd In s.Words
            If Trim(wd) <> vbNullString _
                And wd <> "." _
                And wd.Bold = False Then
                BoldHead = False
            End If
        Next
        If BoldHead Then
            Debug.Print s
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Note that Word has a nasty enough habit of not counting the numbers, it sees them as automatic.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but since it's referring to a Word document by file name, does this effectively mean I'd need to a create a little app to run this outside of Word? Ideally, a macro would be best for the users who will be doing the cleanup.

Comment: No, not at all, you could `Set doc = ActiveDocument`

Comment: Sorry for the late response (I try to enjoy my vacation days when I can :D). I tried this out this morning and it appears to do exactly as I need. I want to test this against a larger document today, but right now it appears this is the solution.

Comment: I ended up tweaking it so that I could search only the first sentence in each paragraph, but this was *exactly* what I needed to finish up my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remou's answer is exactly what I needed, but since StackOverflow is a great resource, this is what I ended up tweaking it to for our particular case:

In particular, the text is within the first sentence of a paragraph. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to catch all of our cases, but it grabs most of them, and gets the user most of the way there.

(Some of the comments below were included on external resources I'd found, so whether they're actually necessary is questionable, but ... it works.)

```
' Do our bold heading replacements
Dim s As Range, p As Paragraph
Dim wd As Range
Dim BoldHead As Boolean
Dim doc As Document

Set doc = ActiveDocument

For Each p In doc.Paragraphs
    Set s = p.Range.Sentences(1)
    If s.Words(1).Bold = True And s.Words(1).Characters(1) = "(" Then
        BoldHead = True
        For Each wd In s.Words
            If Trim(wd) <> vbNullString _
                And wd <> "." _
                And wd.Bold = False Then
                BoldHead = False
            End If
        Next
        If BoldHead Then
            With s.Find
                ' Clear all previously set formatting for Find dialog box.
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = "(\([0-9]@\)) (?@)."

                ' Clear all previously set formatting for Replace dialog box.
                .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                .Replacement.Text = "\1 \2."
                .Replacement.Font.SmallCaps = True
                .Replacement.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
                .Replacement.Font.Bold = False

                ' The following parameters must be set as follows to find only text formatted for the specified font.
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = True
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = True
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False

                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
            End With

            With s.Find
                ' Clear all previously set formatting for Find dialog box.
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = "(\([0-9]@\)) "

                ' Clear all previously set formatting for Replace dialog box.
                .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                .Replacement.Text = "\1" & vbTab
                .Replacement.Font.SmallCaps = False
                .Replacement.Font.Name = "Arial"
                .Replacement.Font.Bold = True

                ' The following parameters must be set as follows to find only text formatted for the specified font.
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = True
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = True
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False

                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next
```